# Flatness over Jacobson ring

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, flatness

I need either a reference or a counter-example to the following statement. Let $A$ be a noetherian Jacobson ring (i.e. a noetherian ring where every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subset A$ is an intersection of maximal ideals). Suppose that $M$ is an $A$-module.

> Is it true that $M$ is flat if and only if
>   $\operatorname{Tor}_1^A(M,A/\mathfrak{m}) = (0)$ for all *maximal
>   ideals* $\mathfrak{m} \subset A$?

Let me point out that I have not assume that $M$ be finitely generated.

Note that under the noetherian hypothesis, the same statement is true with *maximal* replaced by *prime*. See, for example, Lemma 2.1 of these [notes](http://math.berkeley.edu/~robin/math274root.pdf).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/130622/